# What is quasi-aromaticity?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, molecular-structure, molecules, aromaticity

During my study of aromaticity, I came through this topic of *quasi-aromaticity*. Can you please elaborate what Quasi aromatic compounds are and how are they designated?

Comment: Consider using google for such terminology. It has might show good results and is recommended before asking a question. If it is not, then the question is welcome.

Comment: This appears to be the original paper: Lloyd, D.; Marshall, D. R.  Quasi-aromatic compounds: a definition, *Chem. Ind.* (London) **1964**, 1760. Also, there is a modern review by Krygowski et al. ([PDF](https://kundoc.com/pdf-quasi-aromaticitywhat-does-it-mean-.html)). Feel free to improve and narrow-down your question in the meantime.

Comment: @user79161 I completely disagree. We definitely welcome many questions that could "just be Googled." Many of these questions may bring users to less reputable sites like Yahoo answers. If we build up a repository of easily-Googled questions, we start showing up in Google which really grows our site. And it helps people get an authoritative answer.

Comment: @MelanieShebel This site "shows on Google" more then sci. papers, so that point is moot. While the fact that something can be googled isn't a reason to close a question, because like *everything* here can be, users should still provide some context and introduction into the topic in the body of question, otherwise downvotes are are proper reaction.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In general, we can describe a quasi aromatic compound as a compound, which is ionic in nature with a counter ion, and the $\pi$ electrons in such compounds follow Huckel's rule ($4n+2$).

In other words, quasi aromatic compounds are those in which the charges present on the molecule are a part of aromaticity of the compound. A few examples of such compounds are depicted in the diagram:

[image: QuasiAromatic]

However, it has a deeper and broader meaning. For a more in-depth explanation, please read the given references.

---

**References:**

1. T. M. Krygowski, B. Bankiewicz, Z. Czarnocki, M. Palusiak, “Quasi-aromaticity—what does it mean?” *Tetrahedron* **2015**, *71(30)*, 4895–4908 (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tet.2015.05.074).
2. E. Kleinpeter, A. Koch, “Characterization and quantification of *quasi-aromaticity* by spatial magnetic properties (TSNMRS),” *Tetrahedron* **2015**, *71(33)*, 5275–5284 (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tet.2015.06.019).

Comment: The references do not seem to match the answer, as the former tend to emphasize secondary bonding as part of the quasi-aromatic structure and the species do not seem to be charged.  What am I missing?

Comment: @ Oscar Lanzi: I don't think you are missing anything. I think chemists are giving broader picture to existing simple definition. All are still a theory.

Comment: @Melanie Shebel: Thank you for careful (and ruthless! :-)) editing. I'll also take an advantage to congratulate you for your new moderator ship!

Comment: Even though the [gold book](https://goldbook.iupac.org/html/H/H02867.html) calls it Hückel (4n + 2) rule, there are more components to aromaticity than a simple number. Yet it appears that all that ever is taught about aromatic compounds is that number, without any limitations of the generalisation and approximation of these rules. I think it is more important to understand that all compounds that follow Hückel's rules have aromatic character, but not all compounds where aromaticity is observed follow Hückel's rules.